# How do i initialize member variables of a struct if the struct is passed as an argument in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, boolean, structure

Please help!
my structure which i will pass as parameters to functions are:

sumarised code in the context to my query

```
struct mine_index
{
    int row, col;
};
struct miner
{
    bool up, down, right, left;
};

can_solve(mine_index start, mine_index end, miner the_miner)
{
    can_solve(start(row+1,col), end, miner the_miner);
    return ;
}
```

given below is the entire code for the recursive function

```
bool can_solve(mine_index start, mine_index end, miner the_miner)
{

    bool solution[size-1][size-1]
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            solution[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    if(start.row==size-1 && start.col==size-1)//base case 
    {
        solution[start.row][start.row]=1
        return true;
        {
            if(start.row>=0 && start.row<size-1 && start.col>=0 && start.col<size-1) //
            {
                solution[start.row][start.col]=1;
            }
            if(can_solve(start(row+1,col), end, miner the_miner))
            {
                return true;
            }   
            if(can_solve(start(row,col+1), end, miner the_miner))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(can_solve(start(row-1,col), end, miner the_miner))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(can_solve(start(start.row,start.col-1), end, miner the_miner))
            {
                return true;
            }   
        }
```

is this declaration valid if not then is there an alternate way to declare this. I am using a recursive function. the whole function is given below. i now need to work on the logic but i just want to know if my syntax is correct?

Comment: Does it compile?

Answer (score 2):

There're some trivial syntax mistakes in your code.
For example:

- Using keyword **end**
- Wrong open-close curly brace.
- etc...

The first, I think you should try to write code using some C++ IDE (like as CodeBlocks). IDE will notice you your syntax errors. 
Until correct all syntax errors, you can consider function using in next step.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `start(r, c)`, you need just `{r, c}` to create a `mine_index`. So rather than:

```
        if(can_solve(start(row+1,col), end, miner the_miner))
```

you want:

```
        if(can_solve({row+1,col}, end, the_miner))
```

**But** I'm suspicious that each invocation of `can_solve` has its own copy of `solution`.  I think the externally visible function needs to create `solution` (once) and then pass that in to an internal function.  The internal function is then recursive.  (This is actually quite a common pattern for recursive functions:  An external function sets things up and then calls an internal, recursive, function.)